# Why Quarto TOC is not recoqnising markdown headers?

Tags: r, markdown, quarto

I'm trying to programm content of the `HTML` [quarto](https://quarto.org/) document. I.e. I have several functions which return a `Markdown`/`HTML` content. The markdown itself renders OK, however the quarto's table of contents(TOC) does not recognise the headers!

For example, this document has several headers. First was rendered using `shiny::markdown()`, second with the help of `shiny::HTML()` while the third one was written in a plain markdown. The quarto's TOC rendered only the lastone. Is there a possibility to include programmatically written headers in the TOC?

[image]

The code itself:

````
---
title: "Test"
toc: true
format: html
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(shiny)

foo_md <- function(){
  shiny::markdown("## Header generated with foo_md()")
}

foo_html <- function(){
  shiny::HTML("<h2> Header generated with foo_html() </h2>")
}

```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# First header
foo_md()
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in at in sed nibh. Neque dignissim 
ad imperdiet urna urna. In id erat aliquam, dolor ut odio. 
Congue at, non justo fermentum urna suscipit ad torquent posuere. 

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# Second header
foo_html()
```

Suspendisse ad sed, amet nec nunc conubia faucibus. Sociis in
pellentesque nibh. Venenatis at ut imperdiet ornare lectus diam ex
vitae. Id, aenean turpis diam, eget a justo consectetur finibus 
mauris.Vehicula viverra sed volutpat metus placerat tellus non. 
Et nisl. Et duis vel in.

## Ordinary markdown header

Vehicula viverra sed volutpat metus placerat tellus non. Et nisl. Et duis vel in.
````

I'm using Windows machine with quarto version `1.0.38`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include programmatically written headers in TOC, one option is to create that header with `paste` (or with `paste0`), then simply `cat` it with chunk option `results=asis`. Then pandoc filters for quarto will render this header in output HTML document with proper id and class so that TOC can target it.

````
---
title: "Test"
toc: true
format: html
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}

foo_md <- function(){
  x <- "Quarto Header"
  y <- "dynamically generated"
  header <- paste("## ",x, y, "with foo_md()")
  cat(header)
}

```

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
# First header
foo_md()
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in at in sed nibh. Neque dignissim ad
imperdiet urna urna. In id erat aliquam, dolor ut odio. Congue at, 
non justo fermentum urna suscipit ad torquent posuere. 


## Ordinary markdown header

Vehicula viverra sed volutpat metus placerat tellus non. Et nisl. Et duis vel in
````

The rendered document look like this,

[image: html_doc_with_generated_header_in_TOC]

---

But when we create them with `shiny::HTML` or `shiny::markdown`, they are not rendered in the HTML document with the necessary id or tag and TOC can not target them. They are simply rendered as `h2` and we could see them as level2 header in our documnet but not in the TOC.

Comment: Ive also noticed that similar code set up doesnt work for qmd that have only python code chunks. If there are both R and Python code chunks, this works fine. Perhaps has to do with differences between knitr and jupyter