# Quarto toc doesn't recognise ordinary headers

Tags: r, quarto

I can't make the table of contents work on my quarto blog. I tried many many times with different possible solutions, but none worked. Below I provide some examples.

1. Applied `toc: true` to an individual blog post (i also tried by adding `standalone: true` after `toc: true`, since quarto documentation says the table of content doesn't work with `standalone: false`)

```
title: "Dependency management with renv R package"
date: "2022-10-29"
categories: [R, Dependency management]
image: renv_thumbnail.png
format:
  html:
    toc: true
    # standalone: true
    fontsize: 0.9em
    code-tools: true
comments: 
    utterances: 
      repo:  my_repo
      theme: photon-dark
title-block-banner: false
editor: visual
```

And this is what my post looks like after applying the toc.

[image]

I don't know if you can see it, but you might notice the text of my post gets slightly shifted to the left, to make some space for the toc, but no toc actually shows up.

2. Applied `toc: true` globally in my main _quarto.yml file (again, I also tried with `standalone: true`). The result is the same as in step 1, but global.
3. Repeated step 1 and 2, but I placed `toc: true` in the first level of my yaml headers/_quarto.yml file. For example.

```
title: "Dependency management with renv R package"
date: "2022-10-29"
categories: [R, Dependency management]
image: renv_thumbnail.png
toc: true
# standalone: true
format:
  html:
    fontsize: 0.9em
    code-tools: true
comments: 
    utterances: 
      repo:  my_repo
      theme: photon-dark
title-block-banner: false
editor: visual
```

Again, I get the same result as in step 1.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug? Should I delete my .quarto, _freeze and docs (where I output my rendered pages) folders and re-build my site from scratch, maybe? I'd like to avoid this last solution if possible, since some posts take much time to render.

Comment: What do you mean by ordinary headers?!

Comment: @shafee i mean standard headers, the headers you create with hashtags (#, ##, etc.). I specified 'ordinary' because I saw another question where someone had troubles with programmatically generated headers [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398309/why-quarto-toc-is-not-recoqnising-markdown-headers).

Comment: It shows up here, but I do not have the "theme: photon-dark" theme on hand, so first try to remove that and see if all works as expected on the default theme. Note that the `toc` is placed in the `sidebar` I do not know on what conditions that is shown for example in your theme. In the default, the sidebar and therefor the toc is gone for exampe when my browser window gets too small. You can try `toc-location: body`